# How to tilt a ui control(grid, label, etc) along the z-axis

Tags: c#, user-interface, maui

I have an app with a swipe function (similar to Tinder). When swiping, the card currently just moves a bit in the swiped direction and then returns to the center.
Now I want the card not to move along the x-axis in one direction but to tilt around the lower left corner to the left or to the right. Depending on the direction in which you swiped.
I cannot work with rotation in this case, because it is always a rotation around the X or Y axis. What I would need is a rotation around the Z-axis, which of course does not exist for 2-dimensional objects.
Someone has an idea?

Comment: I can't understand the requirement clearly. What is the z-axis in your application.

Comment: There is no z-axis in a 2-D object but when you tilt a rectangle around one of it's points its not the x or y axis. Anyway i want to tilt a rectangle

Comment: Maybe something like [Rotate transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/transforms)?